# what is the difference between 'all the time' and 'all time'

Tags: grammar, differences

I have a confusion regarding the usage of the words all the time and all time, when to use them, please also provide some examples to make them clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All the time** = constantly, or very frequently.

*The bird was calling all the time as we were trying to talk.*

*Why do you telephone me all the time?*

**All time** = through all, or a long period, of history.

*Rembrandt was one of the greatest painters of all time.*